# Permission denied when posting event photos using api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the JavaScript API and having permission problems.  I can post text to /{event-id}/feed and I can upload a photo to /me/photos, but I cannot upload a photo to /{event-id}/photos.  I get an error returned saying permissions is denied.  The Facebook docs don't mention any specific permission that is needed to post to this.  My user is "attending" the event in question and has the following app permissions: publish_actions,user_events,rsvp_event,user_photos.  What could it be?  I've also tried the same thing posting with a page token and that doesn't work either - where again I can post plain text fine using the same page token.  (the event belongs to the page).  Anyone know what I'm missing here?  Thanks!

Comment: Documentation for `/event/photos` says that a user access token with `publish_actions` was enough to post a photo. If that is not the case, then go file a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: We already have a bug report on this if you haven't seen it/you are not the creator of it. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/467975673367173/